# Plot many DIFFERENT images in a loop after some processing

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, image-processing, matlab-figure

I am working with a Matlab code where I want to run a loop.
In each loop, I will do some processing and then show an image based on the processed data.

When I go to the next loop, I want the previously stored image to be closed and generate a new image based on the latest data.

A sum up from my code is this :

```
for ww= 0.4:0.2:2.6
    **********************image processing code*********************************
                  t1=1-ww*(dark_channel1/A); % part that connect ww with the image processing code
    **********************image processing code*********************************
out = pic;
figure;
imshow (out)
imwrite(out,sprintf('%d.jpg',ww));
End;
```

What I expect is many different images depend on the "ww", but the output that I take looks like in each iteration each image sticks to the previous one.

I think that somehow I can’t separate the output (image), and after each iteration I don't reset my loop. As a result I display a new image but stack on the previous. It is like in each iteration the new image sticks to the previous.

Any suggestions??
Thank you in advance

Comment: At the beginning of the loop, clear or pre-initialise `pic`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can i clear the pic?

Comment: You can add a counter in your loop (for example i = i + 1) and use it as number of figure (figure(i)). Therefore, all your images will opening in new figure window. Otherwise, you can include after 'imwrite' the row with 'close all' code. In this case in every iteration you will see only current image (and it will close after finish of the loop).

Comment: We cannot know for sure because you didn't show the important parts of the code. You could try `pic=[];` at the very beginning of the loop.

Comment: Thank you guys you helped me a lot!